# Automatic preview generation with AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex

Right now, when using AUCTeX's preview feature, I have to manually refresh the previews after I change existing sources or  write new text. I have to run `preview-document` every time, which is both inconvenient and inefficient, and it may take a while to re-generate previews for the whole document. I'm looking for a way to

1. Automatically generate previews when I open a document.
2. Automatically update previews on save.
3. Only (re-)compile previews for new and updated pieces of text.

Is there a way to do this with AUCTeX?

Comment: There is a whole set of functions that you can use, such as `preview-at-point` or `preview-section`. They are described [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#Key-bindings-and-user_002dlevel-lisp-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `preview-at-point`?  Whenever I edit a snippet, I do a quick `C-c C-c C-p` (which I think is the default) to recompile only that one part.  `preview-region` (`C-c C-c C-r`) is also useful to avoid having to recompile the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve the same, this is what I could do so far

```
(use-package tex-mode
  :ensure auctex
  :hook (latex-mode . (lambda ()
                        (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda ()
                                                     (preview-document))))))
```

Now, this doesn't actually work and I don't know why, but it could be a step further.

Please reply if you were able to find a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/23105)

Answer (score 0):

The following code in your init file solves your questions

1. Preview on `file-open`
2. Preview on `save-buffer`

```el
(setq preview-auto-cache-preamble t
      TeX-show-compilation nil)

(defun my-initial-preview ()
  "Generate preview at `find-file'."
  (save-excursion
    (preview-document)))

(define-minor-mode my-preview-at-save-mode
  "Preview at `save-buffer'."
  :key ""
  (if my-preview-at-save-mode
      (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my-initial-preview nil t)
    (remove-hook 'after-save-hook #'my-initial-preview)))

;; The Preview package puts `preview-mode-setup` into `LaTeX-mode-hook`.
;; It is important that `my-initial-preview` comes after `preview-mode-setup`.
;; Therefore, we use `with-eval-after-load` and
;; the value `t` for the `depth` argument of `add-hook`.
(with-eval-after-load 'preview
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-initial-preview t)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-preview-at-save-mode))
```

Your question 3 has already been answered by [mbsmu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74368/2370). You just use `preview-at-point`.

Tested with Gnu Emacs 28.1.